# MediaElement not playing the media file defined in the source path?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, mediaelement

I'm getting a very strange error. In my XAML I have two `MediaElement` tags are associated with 2 different sounds. I however, it doesn't play the right one.

**XAML**

```
<MediaElement x:Name="Sound" Source="Sounds/fusrodah.wma" AutoPlay="False" MediaFailed="Sound_MediaFailed" />
<MediaElement x:Name="Sound1" Source="Sounds/yoltorshul.wma" AutoPlay="False" />
<MediaElement x:Name="Sound2" Source="Sounds/iizslennus.wma" AutoPlay="False" />
```

**C#**

```
private void shout_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            this.Sound.Play();

        }
```

By the code written here it should play the media for `Sound` (ie, 'Sounds/fusrodah.wma') instead it plays the sound for `Sound2`(Sounds/iizslennus.wma).

Also I observed that whatever that last `MediaElement` tag's source is what gets played (ie if I added a `Sound3`, its the media for that that would get played.

I don't understand, this is a very strange error. I've listened to the tracks multiple times to make sure I didn't mix them up. I've checked their paths multiple times. Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't play what it is specified to play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one MediaElement on the page. That's why it only plays the last MediaElement added.

Comment: Is there any alternative to use multiple media elements. Please Suggest.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. If your sound files are WAV files, you could use [SoundEffectInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffectinstance.aspx) which will let you play multiple sounds at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I have many MediaElement in my XAML code and I have no problems.

XAML

```
            <MediaElement x:Name="musicPlayer" 
      Source="Assets/sons/rodar2.wav"
      AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="False"/>
            <MediaElement x:Name="musicPlayerFinish" 
      Source="Assets/sons/success.wav"
      AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="False"/>
            <MediaElement x:Name="musicPlayerNavigation" 
      Source="Assets/sons/navegar.wav"
      AudioCategory="BackgroundCapableMedia" AutoPlay="False"/>
```

In my C# code

```
    async void PlayMediaNavigation()
    {
        await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
        {
            musicPlayerNavigation.Play();
        });
    }




    private async void Botan_PointerReleased(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PlayMediaNavigation();
    }
```